# In Visual Studio, using .clang-format, Can I reformat all files at one time in the same directory?

Tags: visual-studio, clang-format

In Visual Studio, I set my own .clang-format and it seems that I can only reformat one file at a time.

Is there any method to reformat all files in this directory? Thanks.

Comment: Run clang-format in a command prompt or PowerShell in that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can add a [Post-build event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp) (not limited C#) to format everything in your project?

Eg. try to add [git-clang-format](https://ortogonal.github.io/cpp/git-clang-format/#:%7E:text=git%2Dclang%2Dformat%20is%20a,on%20the%20changes%20you%20made.) (download and install from [llvm](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/latest)) to Post-build event, post build so that it only formats your code when it can be built successfully, as it might misbehave if the code cannot be properly built.